# sudo npm install em Windows?

Tags: npm

Uso o comando - `sudo npm install` - no mac.

Qual o equivalente deste comando em Windows?

runas?

Estou instalando uma biblioteca em meu servidor local e preciso rodar este comando.

Comment: Minha pergunta se referia a como instalar o gulp.js no Windows.

Instalei o Node.js a partir https://nodejs.org/en/.
Rodei o PowerShell como Administrador e usei o comando: 
npm install gulp-cli -g 
ou seja instalei o gulp.js globalmente.
Agradeço ao Tiago NET que me ajudou com o inicio da resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para instalar qualquer coisa usando npm no windows é da seguinte forma:

```
npm install <pacote> - instala o pacote localmente

npm install -g <pacote> - instala o pacote globalmente
```

Agora esse runas creio ser Run As que traduzindo seria Executar Como ou Rodar como.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Obrigado, Tiago NET.

Comment: Instalei o Node.js a partir https://nodejs.org/en/.

Rodei o PowerShell como Administrador e usei o comando que você ensinou e funcionou.